# Android phone disconnects unexpectedly in developer mode

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, android-sdk-tools

I've built an app in Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.6) using Xamarin & SDK tools (v26.1.1) for a Samsung S8 running Android 8.
I've configured the phone for debug mode and have the Google USB Driver (v11) installed on my PC.

When I attach the phone using USB I can see (and hear) it connect and Visual Studio quickly recognizes the phone as an execution/deployment target. Before I can hit F5 (or Ctrl+F5) the phone disconnects.

I've tried configuring the USB Connection on the phone for MTP and PTP, neither helps. The PTP seemed to hold the connection longer, but it's not conclusive.

Any idea why I'm getting this disconnect issue?
What should I look for?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems I may have been looking too deep.

It may be just a bad USB cable, I'm trying a separate cable now and it seems stable so far.

I'll leave this post up in case the symptoms help another developer.